# How to chain one observable , one regular sync function and another observable at the end

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to utilize the `pipe` command and link from one observable, process the output data in the subscription, then run a function to transform the data and then input the result to a new observable function. I was trying to link the function with the pipe and `switchMap` but I am not sure how to elevate and be able to plug the transform function between the 2 observables

```
service.FirstFunction().pipe( 
     switchMap((info) => this.Transform(info),switchMap((data) => service.secondFunction(data))
 )
.subscription((x)=> this.Updatedata(x));
```

`this.transform` is a regular function and not an observable

thanks

Wally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `this.Transform` does not return an observable, so `switchMap` is not needed here. You can just use `map` instead:

```
service.FirstFunction().pipe( 
  map((info) => this.Transform(info),
  switchMap((data) => service.secondFunction(data))
).subscribe((x)=> this.Updatedata(x));
```

Also, you can simplify the code by passing in function:

```
service.FirstFunction().pipe( 
  map(this.Transform.bind(this)),
  switchMap(service.secondFunction.bind(service))
).subscribe(this.Updatedata.bind(this));
```

You have to bind because the funtions are bind to an object. If there is no this used in the functions you can just skip bind work.

And BTW, to simplify the subscribe work you can also use tap here:

```
service.FirstFunction().pipe( 
  map(this.Transform.bind(this)),
  switchMap(service.secondFunction.bind(service)),
  tap(this.Updatedata.bind(this))
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You don't need the first `switchMap` to transform the data. It could done inside a single `switchMap`.

```js
service.FirstFunction().pipe(
  switchMap(info => service.secondFunction(this.Transform(info)))
).subscription(
  (x) => this.Updatedata(x)
);
```

Comment: thank you , I will test it right now, why sometimes the this is undefined?

Comment: You need to either bind it using `bind(this)` or use arrow function like here. You could learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/6513921).